# Working around group by - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Given this output to one query:

```
ID   |  Question  |  Answer

1    |     1      |    2
1    |     2      |    5
1    |     3      |    5
2    |     1      |    2
2    |     2      |    2
3    |     4      |    7
```

Is there any way in sql to have something like:

```
ID   |  Question  |  Answer
1   
     |     1      |    2
     |     2      |    5
     |     3      |    5
2    
     |     1      |    2
     |     2      |    2
3    
     |     4      |    7
```

The objective is to not repeat ID over and over, but i have nothing to group by for as i want to show all results individually.

I have tried working around GROUP BY but without much results so far.
I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: This is usually done at the application level, not in the database. Databases are good in manipulating rows. You want some rows to be special, like headers, and have different size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- insert extra rows for headings
- remove the ID from the detail row
- make sure the order is correct, so the right headings are over the right details.

Example:

```
select
    -- Show the ID only if it is not a detail row
    case when Question is null then ID else null end as ID,
    Question, 
    Answer
From 
(
    -- Detail rows
    select ID, Question, Answer from T1
    union all
    -- Heading rows
    select distinct ID, cast(null as type) as Question, cast(null as type) as Answer from T1

)x
order by 
    -- In order of ID
    x.ID, 
    -- but make heading rows come first
    case when x.Question is null then 0 else 1 end asc, 
    -- then order by question
    x.Question
```

Answer (score 3):

This **isn't** a SQL problem
 
This **is** a client code presentation problem

Example, in Reporting Services or Crystal Reports, you'd set a Grouping on ID